# google search, json_decode gives null

Tags: php, json

```
    $query = "Poultry meat is a major source of animal protein considering"; 

function fetch_google($query) { 
$cleanQuery = str_replace(" ","+",$query); 

$url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($cleanQuery);
$data=file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data, true); 

for($x=0;$x<count($json->responseData->results);$x++){

echo "<b>Result ".($x+1)."</b>";
echo "<br>URL: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->url;
echo "<br>VisibleURL: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->visibleUrl;
echo "<br>Title: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->title;
echo "<br>Content: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->content;
echo "<br><br>";
}
  } 

  fetch_google($query);
```

i am try to get search result, but in return json_decode giving null values ..
tried searching for answer but failed.

`var_dump($url);`  gives result .. but not $json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loaded the full google search results page. The result in `$data` will be the full `HTML` returned by the page, not a json formatted result.

You need to call the google API in order to receive a JSON that can be easily manipulate from `PHP`

Check the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview) about google search

Comment: Is there any other way to get specific data without api ??

Comment: If you parse the HTML result from http://www.google.com/search?q= you are not sure that will remain in the same format. Maybe tomorrow google decide to change how they display the results. The best option will be to use api and it's the easier one.

Comment: Ok .. please give an example code .. not able to understand google documentation ..

Comment: There are a lot of examples on internet if you don't like google docs. For example check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182662/google-custom-search

Answer (score 0):

Might also have to use this when decoding raw 'google json'

```
$php_json_txt = str_replace('\\x', '\\\\x', $google_json_txt);
$data = json_decode($php_json_txt, true);
```